# Prevent redirect to login for Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, security, redirect, spring-mvc

I have Spring MVC + Spring Security project.

```
<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/security/accessDenied" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">

... 
<intercept-url pattern="/dashboard/myaccount/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_PERSON', 'ROLE_DEALER')"/>
...

<form-login login-page="/security/login" authentication-failure-url="/security/login?error=true"
                default-target-url="/security/success" username-parameter="email"
                password-parameter="secret"/>
<logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/index" logout-url="/security/logout"/>
```

If a user goes to login page, if successful will be redirected to "/security/success" where I do more stuff in the controller with the session object (record userID, ...etc)

My problem is when an GUEST user is going to /dashboard/myaccount (which requires AUTH), he is being redirected to LOGIN page (Which I don't want, I prefer a 404 thrown). After that Spring Security is not redirecting to /security/success. Instead is redirected to /dashboard/myaccount.

I would prefer to find a way to disable completely this redirection to login page in case of GUEST trying to access a AUTH page.

Is any way to do this?

Tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this: always-use-default-target="true"

I this way, my controller function is always invoked after any login.

Comment: Please can you provide a bit more info? Where do we put this? I assumed it goes in application.properties but it doesn't work

Answer (score 14):

We add a new authenticationEntryPoint:

```
<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/security/accessDenied" use-expressions="true"
      disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>

<beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="a.b.c..AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="loginUrl" value="/security/login"/>
</beans:bean>

public class AuthenticationEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {    
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint(String loginUrl)  {
        super(loginUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(403, "Forbidden");
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to create your own AuthenticationEntryPoint, use: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint

Comment: @unify I'm glad I looked at your comment so much cleaner

Comment: Would you please take a look at my question too https://stackoverflow.com/q/47849246/2556354

Comment: Great, following short notation saved me:  `.authenticationEntryPoint(HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))`

Answer (score 10):

In annotated configuration in SpringSecurity 4 you can do:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // ....
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationEntryPoint() {

        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
            if (authException != null) {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                response.getWriter().print("Unauthorizated....");
            }
        }
    });
    // ....
}
```

}

Comment: I found this advice helping me in another situation. Thank you